# scrape( n ′ ​ gcontent−serverapp ′ , ′ How to scrape HTML elements with a specific attribute using Python ′ )

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I have crawled a website, but I have a problem with a special tag that doesn't return the response. I retrieve the HTML document by sending a request and then parse the soup with BS4. However, when I use the find method, it doesn't give me any results.

i used css selector but its not work

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve your question and provide the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], so that everybody could reproduce your issue. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.